# Azure-hosted integration runtime status not found, and Self-Hosted Integration Runtime status unavailable in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: git, azure-data-factory, integration, azure-synapse

In Azure Synapse Analytics, I have two integration runtimes - one Azure and one Self-Hosted. Both of which are not found or unavailable. The data factory is connected to a GIT repository. The two integration runtimes were previously running fine, but have been offline for a number of days. I do not know where to begin to troubleshoot this issue.

[image: Integration Runtimes]

The Self-Hosted Integration Runtime appears online and connected with no issues when I check it from the Microsoft Integration Runtime app on the VM:

[image: Self-Hosted Integration Runtime]

I've also tried running the diagnostics, and the results appear fine:

[image: SHIR Diagnostics]

I do not see anything standing out on the Azure-hosted integration runtime either:

[image: Azure-hosted integration runtime]

If I disconnect the GIT repository from the data factory, however, the Azure-hosted integration runtime status returns to "Running" and the Self-Hosted Integration runtime remains unavailable - so at least for the Azure-hosted integration runtime, there must be an issue related to the GIT configuration:

[image: Status is Running after disconecting GIT configuration]